# vb function returns true when false

Tags: vb.net, function, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to compare two values with each other, my program returns correctly when the condition is met. For example; 9 <= 100, this returns as Re-Order. but if I change 9 to 101 it still returns Re-Order. What could I do to resolve this problem?? Any help is appreciated

```
    Private Function ReOrderPriority() As String
    Dim imp As Integer = 0
    If imp = (StockFrmTxtBox6.Text <= StockFrmTxtBox8.Text) Then
        Return "Re-Order"
    Else
        Return "Not yet applicable"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: it is not `9 <= 100` at all but `"9" <= "100"` .  Turn Option Strict On right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're performing string comparison, not integer comparison. You have to parse your input into `Integer` first.

```
Private Function ReOrderPriority() As String
    If Integer.Parse(StockFrmTxtBox6.Text) <= Integer.Parse(StockFrmTxtBox8.Text) Then
        Return "Re-Order"
    Else
        Return "Not yet applicable"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: +1, probably a bit more idiomatic to use `CInt` here instead of `Integer.Parse`